# JavaScript Function Not Taking Input From Form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a JavaScript function that reads from a form where integers are input. For some reason the function isn't executing. I know this since I have a console.log("hello") call outside the function that prints but a console.log() call inside the function isn't printing. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I read input from the table using getElementByID and then use parseInt to make them integers.

HTML

```
<body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="well">
        <h1 class="text-center">Multiplication Table</h1>
        <p class="text-center">Enter the lowest and highest values to be displayed in
          the multiplication table and the table will generate</p>
      </div>

      <form class="form-inline">
        <label for="row_min" class="mr-sm-2">Row Min</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="row min" id="row_min">
        <label for="row_max" class="mr-sm-2">Row Max</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="row max" id="row_max">
        <label for="col_min" class="mr-sm-2">Col Min</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="col min" id="col_min">
        <label for="col_max" class="mr-sm-2">Col Max</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="col max" id="col_max">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>





  <br>

    <!-- Temoprary placeholder for the table before user input comes in -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="well" id="table-placeholder">
        <h3 class="text-center">Multiplication Table Will Appear Here</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- include the JavaScript at the bottom of the body to laod faster -->
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
var row_min, row_max, column_min, column_max;

  console.log("hello");

function getUserInput() {

  row_min = parseInt(document.getElementById("row_min").value);
  row_max = parseInt(document.getElementById("row_max").value);
  col_min = parseInt(document.getElementById("col_min").value);
  col_max = parseInt(document.getElementById("col_max").value);

  input = document.getElementById("row_max").value;
  row_max = parseInt(userInput);

  input = document.getElementById("col_min").value;
  column_min = parseInt(userInput);

  input = document.getElementById("col_max").value;
  column_max = parseInt(userInput);

  console.log(row_min, row_max, column_min, column_max);
}
```

Comment: You didn't call the `getUserInput()` function.

Comment: You are not calling the function

Comment: The variable userInput isn't defined. I'm pretty sure you mean to call input. In fact, a lot of the code in your function is redundant.

Comment: I eliminated the redundancy, forgot that was in there, and called it. I put "getUserInput()" in my javascript file. It's still says the values are undefined when I print to console.

Comment: Can you edit the code so we can see the most recent version of your code?

Comment: I figured it out. I just added an onclick="getUserInput" to the input tag of the button.